# for...in with array outputs strings instead of numbers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

```
var xs=[]; for (var i in [1,2,3]) xs.push(i); console.log(xs);
```

Why `["0", "1", "2"]` and not `[0, 1, 2]`?

I have the hunch that this is due to array internal implementation.
Array in javascript may be seen as `{"0":1, "1":2, "2":3}`?

EDIT: I write a compiler. I don't care that I don't need to use `for in` and arrays. I don't care about readability of the line. I'd like to know why the keys of the array object are strings and not numbers. Any statements from specification would be appreciated.

Comment: Property keys of objects are (apart from symbols) **always** strings. `for ... in` iterates over property keys. I don't understand how a tutorial, the MDN, or other documentation doesn't already answer this.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, thank you, but why I can create `{1 : 1}` object if properties are always strings?

Comment: It will automatically be converted to `{ "1" : 1 }`. You can check that, e.g. with `let a = { 1: 1 }; a["1"] = 2; console.log(a[1]);`

Comment: So this is some internal conversion? Since `let m = {1:1}; console.log(m);` outputs `{1:1}`. Anyway, thank you, you answered my question. ;)

Comment: [4.3.30 property](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-property): "part of an object that associates a key (**either a String value or a Symbol value**) and a value". If you are interested in the conversion, see [7.1.14 ToPropertyKey ( argument )](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-topropertykey)

Answer (score 4):

Don't loop with `in` on an array.

Loop with `of` :

```
 var xs=[];
 for (var i of [1,2,3]) xs.push(i);
 console.log(xs);
```

Basically, `in` loops on object keys, and `of` loops on array value. The "0" "1" and "2" are keys.

Answer (score 3):

### The problem:

`for...in` loop is not meant to iterate over an array, but was designed to enumerate the object keys. Per the [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> `for...in` should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.

If used with the arrays, the loop treats the array like an object, and considers the indices as the keys (so the stringified keys are printed).

### The quick fix:

The problem with you code is that the statement `for (var i in [1,2,3])` yields the array indices as `i` in the loop body. You may try a simple fix in the loop body:

```
var xs=[]; for (var i in [1,2,3]) xs.push([1,2,3][i]); console.log(xs);
```

You may want to extract `[1,2,3]` in a variable to get the code more readable.

### The recommended fix:

Use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead. It is specifically designed to loop over arrays, and is stable across all environments.

```
var xs=[]; [1,2,3].forEach(item => xs.push(item)); console.log(xs);
```